# How to efficiently feed data into TensorFlow 2.x,

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyspark, tf.data.dataset

I am looking at a data preprocessing task on a large amount of text data and want to load the preprocessed data into TensorFlow 2.x. The preprocessed data contains arrays of integer values since the preprocessing step generates:

- a one hot encoded array as label column
- a tokenized list of tokens per data row
- an activation mask for usage in transformers

So, I've been thinking I'll use pyspark to pre-process the data and dump the result into a `JSON` file (since CSV cannot store structured data). Thus far, everythings works out OK. But I am having trouble processing the `JSON` file in `tf.data.Dataset` (or anything else that scales as efficient and can interface with TensorFlow 2.x).

I do not want to use/install an additional library (eg TensorFlowOnSpark) besides Tensorflow and PySpark so I am wondering whether its possible to link the two in an efficient way using JSON files since there seems to be no other way for saving/loading records containing a list of data(?). The JSON test file looks like this:

```
readDF = spark.read.format('json').option('header',True).option('sep','|').load('/output.csv')
readDF.select('label4').show(15, False)

+---------------------------------------------------------+
|label4                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, the **label4** column has already been one hot encoded and the tokenized text column will look similarly once the tokenizer was applied to it. So, my question is: Can a `JSON` file be loaded efficiently (maybe via generator function) with `tf.data.Dataset` or should I go down a different road (with an additional library) for this one?

Answer (score 1):

The [`tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) provides several ways to efficiently consume data from different sources. And while I would say a "cleaner" solution might be to handle the pre-processing using TensorFlow itself, let me suggest a couple of ideas for your use case:

#### 1) one-hot encoding

I can see that you preprocess the data and store the entire one-hot encoded vector, which will penalise your data transference, since you will be reading mostly zeros, as opposed to the actual label of interest. I would suggest encoding this as an integer, and transforming it to a one hot encoding using a python generator on ingestion. Alternatively, if you're using a categorical cross-entropy loss function, you can use a label encoding (encode each class as an integer), and use the [sparse categorical cross entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) instead.

If you already have one-hot-encoded lists, you can simply use `my_list.index(1)` to get the label encoding (it's the same as the index of the only 1 in the vector after all.)

#### 2) using a generator

This is totally possible using `tf.data`. In fact, they provide the [`from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) function to wrap python genetaros to be used for ingesting data into your model. As found in the documentation, this is how you would use it:

```py
def gen():
  ragged_tensor = tf.ragged.constant([[1, 2], [3]])
  yield 42, ragged_tensor

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     gen,
     output_signature=(
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32),
         tf.RaggedTensorSpec(shape=(2, None), dtype=tf.int32)))

list(dataset.take(1))
```

#### 3) consider going back to CSV

If you're working with massive amounts of data, you can probably work around JSON encodings and encode some structure within CSV-like formats, such as TSV, and if you need a list-like column, you can use other separators (for instance, you can separate columns by `\t`, and then you can separate elements within each column using `,` or `|`, or whatever character causes fewer collisions with your existing data.

As an example, let's assume your CSV file has the following structure:

```
comlumn name 1, column name 2, column name 3, column name 4
0.1,0.2,0.3,0:0:0:1
0.1,0.2,0.3,0:0:1:0
0.1,0.2,0.3,0:1:0:0
...
```

That is you have 4 columns separated by `,`, and the 4th colum is in itself a list of values separated by `:`, which also are one hot representation of 4 classes, a generator that you could use with the code above is:

```py
def my_generator(filename):
    first_line = True
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if first_line:
                # do something to handle the header
                first_line = False
                continue
            fields = line.split(',')
            # here you extract the index of the one-hot encoded class
            label = fields[3].split(':').index(1)
            fields[3] = label
            yield fields # return a list of features and the class
```

Comment: Can you give sample python codes (or links towards each option)? I like option 2) but have no idea how I could wrap a generator (eg reading from python) to be consumed by tf.data :-( Option 3) is also interesting but can you give a python sample on how a hot coded list (I am also looking at multi hot encoding) can be decoded for tf.data when it was coded like this '0,1,0,0,0,0'?

Comment: I added some code snippets and links to the relevant documentation are there, just click on `tf.data` or `from_generator`, they're formatted like code, but they're links :)

Comment: The generator function does not read a JSON or CSV file or any file that contains a list in its column. I can look up the documentation too but I need to solve this specific problem of reading a structured list with tf.data. How do I do this practically within the generator function or any of the other 3 approaches?

Comment: The `from_generator` function will create the `tf.data.Dataset` object and ingest the data that the generator provides, how to parse the JSON or csv is up to the generator itself. That is why I was suggesting using a CSV instead, you could write a custom CSV parser as a python generator, that understands that, say, the 4th column should be interpreted as a list.

Comment: But what does the generator that understands the 4th column as a list and populates it as such look like? This was the original question and just skipping it is not a helpful answer because I am still not able implement a more effective strategy here :-(

Comment: I added a simple example that you can use to build your own generator. Unfortunately, without a specific example of the data, I can't provide a specific generator that works for your case, there are just too many possible formats and the solution would be useless for any other file :/